# Exclude control characters with DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am using DataContractSerializer to serialize list of objects to XML. Data for object's properties come from the database and columns in the database can contain control characters that are invalid in XML.
Is it possible somehow to instruct DataContractSerializer to automatically exclude control characters that are invalid?

Here's the code I am using

```
serializer = new DataContractSerializer(myList.GetType());
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   serializer.WriteObject(ms, myList);
   return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to add a separate property for serialization (it can be even private). In this property you can return the string to serialize (without control characters).

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass 
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    private string MyPropertyForSerialization
    {
        get 
        {
            return RemoveControlCharacters(this.MyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.MyProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `MyProperty` is *not* marked with `DataMember` attribute - the `MyPropertyForSerialization` is marked with the attribute instead.

The code also assumes that you have a RemoveControlCharacters method which removes control characters from the specified string.